# Bypassing Login screen with proxy for front-end local development

Tags: tomcat, proxy, sapui5, connect, http-proxy

I have been trying to setup a local development environment for UI5 development. I was successful to serve my static files (controllers, views, etc.) with the localhost server (Apache Tomcat/Nodejs Connect) and also able to avoid CORS issue with proxy server (proxy servlet, Nodejs http-proxy). It works fine when the OData/REST api server has either no authentication or dialog based authentication. However, currently the problem I am facing is that my proxy server doesn't work in case of page based authentication (logon page, etc.). Any suggestions on how to bypass the Login screen and setup the environment?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to pass through the page based authentication in your case. However if all your need is to setup a local development environment, you might want to try this approach [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome) .

I have a separate shortcut with the target;

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
>   --user-data-dir="C:/FolderName" --disable-web-security

I'm using WebStorm and I've configured this as my default browser. It is pretty convenient for me right now. I don't need to start browser using parameters every time in order to get a CORS-ALLOWED instance and I also don't even need to click the shortcut.

Answer (score -2):

put the user name and password in the model
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html#constructor